# Триггер на закрытие программы на Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Мне нужно сделать так, что бы когда программа закрывалась, я смог это отследить и на основе этого что то сделать, в моем случае это занести это в мой логфайл.

```
from tkinter import *
и остальные библеотеки...

def exit1():
   print('exit')


logging.basicConfig(filename='LogFile.log', level=logging.INFO)

class Window:

там идут функции некоторые

if __name__ == '__main__':

try:
    exit1()
except RuntimeError as error:
    print(error)
finally:
    logging.info(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + " Closing the 
    program")

window = Window(600, 500, "Название программые")
window.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Мне нужно сделать так, что бы когда программа закрывалась

Код после инструкции *finnaly*, это последнее что делает Python Interpreter, перед закрытием программы.

```
def main():
    print('Hello World')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
        raise RuntimeError()
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        print('Bye bye...') 
        # Здесь можно записать данные в лог  
        # Даже если возникнет исключение
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло

Comment: С чем связанно, то, что у меня сначала пишется в логах, что прога закрылась, а только потом, те действия которые были сделаны в проге? Как это пофиксить можно, sleep() не работает

Comment: Приведите код, я ведь не вижу последовательность действий.

Comment: Привел примерный код

Comment: Под "прога закрылась", вы подразумеваете вызов  функции exit1?

Comment: "действия которые были сделаны в проге" где этот момент в скрипте?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122862/discussion-between--and-karlson12).

Answer (score 1):

Дополню, что можно обрабатывать разные сигналы которые поступают программе с помощью модуля `signal`. В этом примере регистрируется обработчик для сигнала `SIGINT` - сигнал для остановки процесса пользователем с терминала`Ctrl + C`. В библиотеке можно найти полный перечень сигналов. При нажатии `Ctrl + C` - будет выполнен код `signal_handler`.

```
import signal
import time

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    print('handler start') 
    time.sleep(1)  # тут можно выполнить любую операцию
    print('sleepeng')

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)   # регистрация обработчика

while 1:
    print(1)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Стоит учесть, что Обработчики сигналов выполняются в основном потоке Python, независимо от того из какого потока был получен. Это означает, что сигналы не могут использоваться в качестве средства связи между потоками.